# Getting the current version of Datamodel Core data

Tags: core-data, core-data-migration, xcdatamodel

Is method to get the version number of data model from the application. In my application already version 2-3 migration is done and I am adding a new version to the data model. So I need to handle the migration, I need to do the 2-3 first and then 3-4 and if the existing application is running on data model version 3, then need to execute only 3-4 migration.